# Creating dictionary with same values in all elements

Tags: ansible

I have dictionary like this:

```
     abc:
        xyz1:
          url: "{{ url }}"
          api_key: "{{ key }}"
        xyz2:
          url: "{{ url }}"
          api_key: "{{ key }}"
        xyz3:
          url: "{{ url }}"
          api_key: "{{ key }}"
```

I know that all xyz{number} have the same values in url and api_key and will have same values in the future.

I need this nested format, but what will be more elegant way to write this instead the way I did it (which will be quite long with few more elements)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create template

```
shell> cat myvars.yml.j2
abc:
{% for index in range(1, size+1) %}
  xyz{{ index }}:
    url: "{{ '{{'  }} url {{ '}}' }}"
    api_key: "{{ '{{'  }} key {{ '}}' }}"
{% endfor %}
```

The playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    size: 3
    key: mykey
    url: myurl
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: myvars.yml.j2
        dest: myvars.yml
    - include_vars: myvars.yml
    - debug:
        var: abc
```

will create file `myvars.yml`

```
shel> cat myvars.yml
abc:
  xyz1:
    url: "{{ url }}"
    api_key: "{{ key }}"
  xyz2:
    url: "{{ url }}"
    api_key: "{{ key }}"
  xyz3:
    url: "{{ url }}"
    api_key: "{{ key }}"
```

and debug will display the included variable

```
    "abc": {
        "xyz1": {
            "api_key": "mykey", 
            "url": "myurl"
        }, 
        "xyz2": {
            "api_key": "mykey", 
            "url": "myurl"
        }, 
        "xyz3": {
            "api_key": "mykey", 
            "url": "myurl"
        }
    }
```